# angular 6 issue uisng flatMap. What's wrong?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I'm trying to use flatMap in order to fulfill requests one by one using result of the first request in the second one. Via debugger i do see that reach first service, but not the second one. What's wrong?
Thanx in advance!

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < MedicalCheckup[] > {
  return this.appStateService.getSelectedPatient()
    .pipe(flatMap(
      patient =>
      this.examinationService.getExaminations(patient.id, ExaminationsSelectionPeriod.THREE_MONTHS.toString())
    ));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're not subscribing. Maybe the first service returns an empty observable or throws an error.

Comment: nope, i do not see errors. That's a problem.
And i use the same method in different place and it's ok. I'm pretty sure that this service do not return empty observable.

Comment: Subscribe to observable

Comment: I don't think we have sufficient info here. Can you show us any more code?